# Storage size of NFC Tag

Tags: nfc

I have an NXP NTAG216 and I want to know the storage size of the tag. From the specification I read that the size of the data area is in `Block 3` `Byte 2` which is `7F` in my case which is `127` in decimal and times `8 Bytes` it is `1016 Bytes`. From the NXP website It states that the tag only has `924 Bytes` [NXP NTAG 213/215/216](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/ntag/ntag-for-tags-labels/ntag-213-215-216-nfc-forum-type-2-tag-compliant-ic-with-144-504-888-bytes-user-memory:NTAG213_215_216).

```
[0]    04 : 91 : 52 : 4F
[1]    9A : 9A : 40 : 80 
[2]    C0 : 48 : 00 : 00 
[3]    E1 : 10 : 7F : 00
```

Similar with a NXP NTAG215 which has `3E` in decimal `62` times `8 Bytes` is `496 Bytes` where the website says `540 Bytes`.

```
[0]    04 : 34 : DB : 63 
[1]    6A : 83 : 5C : 81 
[2]    34 : 48 : 00 : 00 
[3]    E1 : 10 : 3E : 00
```

Can someone explain to me how this number is calculated?

Comment: Just for the close voter: This is one question with two examples.

Comment: true, but its too broad and not really on topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the datasheet for cards https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf

It says

NTAG216 EEPROM:

- 924 bytes, organized in 231 pages of 4 byte per page.
- 26 bytes reserved for manufacturer and configuration data
- 37 bits used for the read-only locking mechanism
- 4 bytes available as capability container
- 888 bytes user programmable read/write memory

From the spec for Type 2 cards http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf

> The Capability Container Byte 2 indicates the memory size of the data area of the Type 2 Tag Platform. The value of byte 2 multiplied by 8 is equal to the data area size measured in bytes

Note your question said multiply by `8Bits` (1 Byte) which is wrong, I'm sure this was just a typo and you meant `8Bytes`

So some of the headline 924 bytes is actually reserved for other uses and would never be included in the size listed in the Capability Container that leave 888 bytes to use of user usable memory.

The datasheet says the value in the should be `6Dh` which is 109 * 8 = 872 bytes.
And all my NTAG216 have a value of `6Dh`

I'm not sure why this value Capability Container value is less than the actual usable memory size, it might because the wording of the spec is unclear but it might be "usable data area" of a NDEF message and might not include the mandatory headers (TLV, etc) that make up a valid NDEF message and Records.

So the the NTAG215 example value of `3Eh` is exactly as the datasheets says it should be and smaller than the total memory size as outlined above because some memory pages are reserved for non NDEF data, etc.

The next question is why is your NTAG216 example not have the correct value of `6Dh`

The spec for Type 2 cards and the datasheet the NTAG21x cards says:-

> The Capability Container CC (page 3) is programmed during the IC production according to the NFC Forum Type 2 Tag specification (see Ref. 2). These bytes may be bit-wise modified by a WRITE or COMPATIBILITY_WRITE command. The parameter bytes of the WRITE command and the current contents of the CC bytes are bit-wise OR’ed. The result is the new CC byte contents. This process is irreversible and once a bit is set to logic 1, it cannot be changed back to logic 0.

The 4 bytes of the Capability Container have to be writeable because you can only write in blocks of 4 bytes and Byte 3 of the Capability Container indicates the read and write access capability of the data area and CC area of the Type 2 Tag Platform and therefore can be legitimately changed to make the card read only.

So it is possible that a bad write to the Capability Container has increased the value of the Byte 2 (size value) to an invalid value on this particular card.

The other possibility is that there are a lot of Fake NTAG21x cards around, may be this is a fake card with actually more memory than a genuine NXP card.
Either use the `Originality signature` method outlined in the datasheet to verify it is genuine or the `Taginfo` smartphone App from NXP will also verify it is genuine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes it looks like the 216 tag got a bad write because I have another one with the correct size. And you are also right it's 8 byte not bits (will edit)

Comment: On more question: When an 216 tag has 231 pages does it mean 0-231 pages (232 count) or just 231 because a READ command always returns 4 blocks per read. I see some non zeros in page 231 and I wonder what that is?

Comment: Section 8.5 of the datasheet says 0 - 230 (so 231 pages), For the Non-Zero's Section 10 of the datasheet say for reads past the end of the address range due to 4 block read have "A roll-over mechanism is implemented to continue reading from page 00h once the end of the accessible memory is reached", so you are seeing data from the beginning of the card.